# How to get checked out SPListItem for current user by file name using CAML query?

Tags: caml-query, splistitem, check-out

I use SharePoint 2010 RTM and now I'm trying to get SPListItem, which was checked out by current user, using code like this:

```
                query.Query = "<OrderBy>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                              "</OrderBy>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                                "<And>" +
                                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' LookupId='true'/><Value Type='User'>" + SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName + "</Value></Eq>" +
                                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /><Value Type='Text'>" + strFileShortName + "</Value></Eq>" +
                                "</And>" +
                            "</Where>";
            query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
            SPListItemCollection itemCol = spl.GetItems(query);
```

But itemCol is always empty. Any suggestions what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID` with `Type='User'`
2. LinkFilename has 'Computed' type.
   For details:

   - MSDN forums discussion: [Not able to search list using LinkFileName](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ff4d255d-684f-4388-b1df-e7f1cbb08d4d/)